# Existence of functions on a Compact hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I am supposed to use urysohn lemma in part (a) but for that i need to find closed sets in X  I am not sure how to do it. I wish U1 and U2 were disjoint then it would have been easier.
Help please.

Comment: Did you try working with the complements of $U_1, U_2$? I didn't try to prove yet, but that would be my first guess.

Comment: But then they may not be disjoint right @PaulK

Comment: $U_1^c \cap U_2^c = (U_1 \cup U_2)^c = X^c = \emptyset$ by de morgans law?

Comment: Oh yes silly me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use that $X$ is normal to find $F_1 , F_2$ closed in $X$ so that $F_1 \subseteq U_1$ and $F_2 \subseteq U_2$ and $F_1 \cup F_2 = X$.
(Note that $X\setminus U_1$ and $X\setminus U_2$ are closed and disjoint in $X$.)

Then find Urysohn functions $g_i $ to $[0,1]$ that are $1$ on $F_i$ and $0$ on $X\setminus U_i$ for $i=1,2$. Now do some scaling (both $g_i$ are already supported on $U_i$, now fix the sum property).

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana follow the proof hint and it follows.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana separate the complements of the $U_i$ and take the complement of the separating open sets.

Comment: Okkay almost clear what is fix the sum property?@HennoBrandsma

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana think. Consider $g_1+ g_2$. Is it ever $0$? The functions we want should sum to $1$ everywhere.

Comment: Don't we need the sets Fi to be disjoint because otherwise the function g1+g2 may get value 2 at their intersection.??@HennoBrandsma

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana that’s no problem after the compensation step

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana both functions are defined on $X$, being Urysohn functions.

Comment: Just final question  the function g1+g2 may get value 2 at their intersection how to deal with it @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana ok, if you cannot figure it out: divide each $g_i$ by the sum. The sum of those equals $1$.

Comment: That means gi changes to gi÷(g1+g2) then clearly it's sum is 1. That's brilliant. Thanks@HennoBrandsma